# input type number not showing arrows button in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

When I see in [Can I use input number](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) then it says that IE10+ has partial support.

But when I use input type number then it doesn't display arrows buttons which is used for increasing or decreasing the value. It just shows the simple textbox.

And as per the Can I use, the partial support, I think there may be something need to make it work in IE10+ may be prefix or something else?

I don't want to use a pollyfill for this simple style.

Comment: You either need a polyfill for this, or you need to use jQuery plugin for this.

Comment: In Can I Use: UI widget does not include increment/decrement buttons.

Comment: If that is less line of code then it would be okay for me.

Comment: How less number of line do you want?

Comment: http://html5please.com/#number

Comment: https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill

Comment: that I already saw but huge file size.

Comment: The min js file is 1 line! `:P`

Comment: Man, I was just kidding!!! Can't you see the smiley!